# Deploy ASP.NET Core image to Azure Kubernetes Service via visual studio 2019

Tags: azure, kubernetes, visual-studio-2019, azure-aks

Is it possible to deploy the image generated from the example below to Azure Kubernetes Service via visual studio 2019?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/tutorial-kubernetes-tools?view=vs-2019

What are the easiest way to deploy that?

Comment: As I know the easiest way is to just deploy the image to AKS, not through the visual studio. You can use the visual studio to create the image and charts.

Comment: Please can you provide an example to deploy to AKS, ideally starting from creating projects for Kubernetes Orchestration.

Comment: I do not mean using the visual studio. You can use the visual studio to create the image and put it to the ACR. Then just use it in the yaml file, not through the visual studio.